# Rails select tag using belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have the following models:

Product:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
...
end
```

User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end
```

In my products view I need a drop down list of users, and when a user is selected, it should be associated with that specific product.

This is my view:

```
<%= form_tag (update_user_products_path) do %>
<%@products.each do |product| %>
            <div class = "prod">
            <a href='<%= recommendations_path(:product_id => product.id, :rating_set_id => params[:rating_set_id]) %>' target="_blank"><img src='<%= product.cover_img %>' class='product_image_prods'></img></a>
            <div class= "title"><small><b><%= link_to truncate(product.title, :length =>30),  recommendations_path(:product_id => product.id, :rating_set_id => params[:rating_set_id]), :target => '_blank' %></b></small></div>
            <br/>
            <div><em>Current Rating: <%= product.rating %> </em></div>
            <%= hidden_field_tag :product_id, product.id %>
            <%= select_tag "user_id", options_for_select(User.all.collect {|u| [ u.name, u.id ] })%>
            </div>

            <% end %>
    <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

I am confused as to if I should use form_tag and updated the Product.user_id, or should use nested_attributes for the user model in my product from?

**UPDATE:**

Products Controller Action:

```
def update_user
    @product = Product.find(params["product_id"])
    @product.update_attribute(:user_id, params[:user_id])
    redirect_to :back, :flash => { :notice => "Updated users" }
  end
```

Also updated my view. How do I update all product records with the correct user_id. Currently, when I submit my from, it updates just 1 product record.

Comment: How are you going to associate them?  with Ajax or on form submit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is figure which user was associated with which product.

For example (hooking the tag with `product.id`)

```
<%= form_tag(update_user_path, :id => "update_user_form") do %>
   <%@products.each do |product| %>
      <%= select_tag "user_id:#{product.id}", options_for_select(User.all.collect {|u| [ u.name, u.id ] })%>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

When you submit you will get the the key with the product id and the selected user's id.

For example lets say `product.id = 1` and `user.id = 2`

`params` will include

```
key => user_id:1 value=> 2
```

so taking the key and splitting it on `:` will give you the `product_id` then getting the value of that hash entry will give you the selected `user.id` for that product.

Comment: How do I separate the Key and ID in my controller? Calling params[:user_id] does not return anything. Thanks!